Why does the mass-energy equivalence apply to binding energy when it is derived purely through kinematic means?
I understand that by defining the four velocity, multiplying it by the rest mass and taking the entire thing's norm we get $E^2=m^2+p^2$, but how does this apply to binding energy, or in general energy of a potential or field when there is no four velocity to speak of?
I understand that energy-mass equivalence is universal but I would like to know why. In addition, is there a most general definition of energy that would work for all physics (does it come from symmetry with Noether's theorem)? Please provide a technical answer or point out a specific field of study if possible.

Actually, it is quite confusing why you would think the way you do. Once you understand that it is an equivalence, then you should already understand that not just all mass is energy, but rather that, also, all energy is mass. Thus, binding energy is also going to show up on the mass calculation. In a sense, physics is not trying to explain why the stuff works the way it does, but that we notice that it works this way and quantify exactly how it works.


I understand that by defining the four velocity, multiplying it by the rest mass and taking the entire thing's norm we get E2=m2+p2

This is not always an accurate description of the process. For some objects we start with the four-momentum. With the four-momentum then we directly obtain the mass as the Minkowski norm. In other cases, it is true that we can construct the four-momentum by knowing the mass and the four-velocity, but there is no requirement to always do it that way.

how does this apply to binding energy, or in general energy of a potential or field when there is no four velocity to speak of?

For extended objects, particularly in curved spacetime, there may not be a four-momentum. In such cases the best that you can do is work with the stress-energy tensor. You cannot necessarily integrate the stress-energy at each point to get an overall four-momentum, and therefore you cannot always calculate a mass or an energy. In such cases the famous equation doesn't apply.
For binding energy, as long as the curvature is asymptotically flat and the energy (both binding and other energy) is localized to some small portion of the manifold, then you can treat the binding energy as a negative energy that is a portion of the four-momentum of the total object.
For example, suppose a proton at rest has four-momentum $P^\mu=(938,0,0,0) \mathrm{\ MeV/c}$ and an electron at rest has four-momentum $e^\mu=(511,0,0,0) \mathrm{\ keV/c}$. When they combine they emit a photon with four-momentum $p^\mu=(14,-14,0,0) \mathrm{\ eV/c}$. The resulting hydrogen atom has a four-momentum of $H^\mu=(938510986,14,0,0) \mathrm{\ eV/c}$. In the center of momentum frame that is a four-momentum of $H^\mu=(938510986,0,0,0) \mathrm{\ eV/c}$. This can be thought of as the sum of a proton and an electron and a binding energy of four-momentum $b^\mu=(-14,0,0,0) \mathrm{\ eV/c}$.

Your answer put me on a long detour. Apparently the experiments are far from being able to directly verify this: The codata cited values of the mass of proton, mass of electron, and the ciaaw value of the mass of hydrogen together gives the binding energy as a laughable 13.3 eV. Instead, the experimental and theoretical values for the binding energy directly is far more precise. I'm sure you know that it would need you to be more careful to show a sensible 4-vector computation.

@naturallyInconsistent it is just an example. That is why I said “for example” and “suppose”
